# selectInput = NULL for numeric column for Shiny widgets

Tags: r, shiny

I am having a small problem with widgets in Shiny. After starting Shiny app I would like to have (as default) selected=NULL for all my widgets. However it is not working for numeric columns at all (factor ones are fine), and after starting i get the first value in this column. Even changing numeric to factor does not help.

My code, as example

```
selectInput("XX", h3("XX:"), choices = as.list(levels(as.factor(data$XY))),selected=NULL)
```

Comment: You can try  add `""` to list `as.list(c("",levels(as.factor(aaa[[1]]))))`

Comment: Great! Thanks! It actually did work! Many many thanks!

Comment: I wonder why you convert it to a list, `levels(as.factor(data$XY))` should be fine as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `""` to `choices` of `selectInput`

For example

```
require(shiny)
aaa=data.frame(c("a",'b','c'))
shinyUI(fluidPage(

      selectInput("s1", "Select 1", choices = as.list(c("",levels(as.factor(aaa[[1]])))))


  )
)
```